# How do we filter for subdocument mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Given a schema like

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  price: {type:Number},
 condition: {
    new: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    heat: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    AC: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }
);
```

I want to find only those that has new as true and the rest can be either true or false. So we do not care about the rest of the subdocument.
query = {new: true} so the rest of the keys will be undefined. I am able to that what I want with non subdocument meaning those that are not in subdocument.

Model.find(query)

What I tried?:

```
1. query = {condition.new: true} I think it is improper syntax
2. query = {condition: {new: true}} this will return an empty list because every elements need to contain the rest of the element
3. query = {condition: {new: true, heat: {$or: [true, false], AC:{$or :[true, false]}}
This will return an empty list
```

Comment: just try this `"condition.now": true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is correct, but you need to enclose the path in quotes. So this is what it should look like:

```
db.collection.find({
  "condition.new": true
})
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GL09AqeR2Y4

Comment: I am getting an empty list.

Comment: @Justastudent Show you sample data and show exactly how you're querying it. (in mongoose or in terminal)

Comment: Ah nevermind I gotit. The issue was in the schema I set the default to false. So when I try to do that I think by default it put the rest to false. Is it right?